# Joining 3 columns from one table to 1 column in another table

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm trying to join Table1 to Table2 as shown below:

Table1:

```
| RecCurr | PayCurr | MTMCurr | TradeID |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| USD     | CAD     | JPY     |    1234 |
```

Table2:

```
+------+-------+
| Curr | Value |
+------+-------+
| USD  |    10 |
| CAD  |    11 |
| JPY  |    12 |
+------+-------+
```

Joined table:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| RecCurr | PayCurr | MTMCurr | TradeID | RecValue | PayValue | MTMValue |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| USD     | CAD     | JPY     |    1234 |       10 |       11 |     12   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

So far, the only solution I have is the following:

```
SELECT T1.RecCurr, T1.PayCurr, T1.MTMCurr, T2.RecValue, T3.PayValue, T4.MTMValue
FROM
(SELECT RecCurr, PayCurr, MTMCurr FROM Table1) T1,
(SELECT RecCurr, RecValue FROM Table2) T2,
(SELECT PayCurr, PayValue FROM Table2) T3,
(SELECT MTMCurr, MTMValue FROM Table2) T4

where T1.RecCurr = T2.RecCurr
and T1.PayCurr = T3.PayCurr
and T4.MTMCurr = T4.MTMCurr
```

Is there a cleaner solution that doesn't require me to join Table2 3 times with Table1?

Comment: Why do your rows in table 2 become columns?

Comment: Which Sybase product (ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: Following works on ASE; me thinks it should work on SQLAnywhere (and IQ) but I don't have a SQLAnywhere db up and running at the moment ...

If you only want to do a single join to Table2 then you'll need a query that performs a table pivot.

First the setup:

```
create table Table1
(RecCurr char(3)
,PayCurr char(3)
,MTMCurr char(3)
,TradeID int)
go

insert Table1 values ('USD','CAD','JPY',1234)
go

create table Table2
(Curr  char(3)
,Value int)
go

insert Table2 values ('USD',10)
insert Table2 values ('CAD',11)
insert Table2 values ('JPY',12)
go

select * from Table1
go

 RecCurr PayCurr MTMCurr TradeID
 ------- ------- ------- -----------
 USD     CAD     JPY            1234

select * from Table2
go

 Curr Value
 ---- -----------
 USD           10
 CAD           11
 JPY           12
```

An example query with a single join to Table2:

```
select  T1.RecCurr,
        T1.PayCurr,
        T1.MTMCurr,
        T1.TradeID,
        sum(case when T2.Curr = T1.RecCurr then T2.Value else 0 end) as RecValue,
        sum(case when T2.Curr = T1.PayCurr then T2.Value else 0 end) as PayValue,
        sum(case when T2.Curr = T1.MTMCurr then T2.Value else 0 end) as MTMValue
from    Table1 T1,
        Table2 T2
where   T2.Curr in (T1.RecCurr, T1.PayCurr, T1.MTMCurr)
group by T1.RecCurr, T1.PayCurr, T1.MTMCurr, T1.TradeID
go

 RecCurr PayCurr MTMCurr TradeID     RecValue    PayValue    MTMValue
 ------- ------- ------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
 USD     CAD     JPY            1234          10          11          12
```

And for those with allergies to comma's (in the `FROM` clause):

```
select  T1.RecCurr,
        T1.PayCurr,
        T1.MTMCurr,
        T1.TradeID,
        sum(case when T2.Curr = T1.RecCurr then T2.Value else 0 end) as RecValue,
        sum(case when T2.Curr = T1.PayCurr then T2.Value else 0 end) as PayValue,
        sum(case when T2.Curr = T1.MTMCurr then T2.Value else 0 end) as MTMValue
from    Table1 T1
join    Table2 T2
on      T2.Curr in (T1.RecCurr, T1.PayCurr, T1.MTMCurr)
group by T1.RecCurr, T1.PayCurr, T1.MTMCurr, T1.TradeID
go

 RecCurr PayCurr MTMCurr TradeID     RecValue    PayValue    MTMValue
 ------- ------- ------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
 USD     CAD     JPY            1234          10          11          12
```

Answer (score 0):

There is *always* a better way to write a query when it has commas in the `FROM` clause.  In addition, the subqueries are unnecessary:

```
SELECT T1.RecCurr, T1.PayCurr, T1.MTMCurr,
       T2r.RecValue, T2p.PayValue, T2m.MTMValue
FROM T1 JOIN
     Table2 t2r
     ON T2r.RecCurr = T1.RecCurr JOIN
     Table2 t2p
     ON t2p.PayCurr = t1.PayCurr
     Table2 t2m
     ON t2m.MTMCurr = t1.MTMCurr;
```